# Plotting two functions that approach 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to plot to functions in one diagram. Both of these functions approach 0 when going towards x=0
[image: Those are the graphs i get]

**Here's the code:**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#needed variables.
m1= 2e+24
m2= 3e+30
m3= 2e+16
m4= 3e+25
G = 1.6e-11
r = np.linspace(0,1e+50,50)

#first function U(r).
def U(r): 
    return -(G*m1*m2)/r 
Ur_name = r'$U(x)=\frac{-(G*m1*m2)}{r}$'
y=U(r) 

#second function U2(r).
def U2(r):
    return -(G*m3*m4)/r
U2r_name= r'$U2(x)=\frac{-(G*m3*m4)}{r}$'
y2=U2(r)


#plotting both functions.
plt.plot(r, y, label=Ur_name)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.plot(r,y2, label=U2r_name)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

When I plot them separately, it is all good. But as soon as i plot them together, shit hits the fan.

Edit: The orange graph should not be straight, it should behave like the other curved graph as the only thing that changed were two variables
(m1 to m3, m2 to m4)

Comment: what is this error? it seems to plot a graph..

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what is wrong with your plot and what you expect it to look like?

Comment: The 2nd plot is just straight, which it shouldnt be. It should basically behave like the curved graph

Comment: The values of `U2()` are so tiny compared to those of `U()`, that the plot actually IS a flat line when viewed with the same Y axis values.  Take a closer look at the axis labels on the separate plots...

Comment: Oh yeah, you are so right. Thx for the tip. I totally didnt put that into account, as i thought that the difference cant be so big, but yeah, youre right.

Comment: You are also doing a division by 0, which creates problems. Instead of using 0 as the first argument of `linspace` when creating `r`, try to use something like `1e-5` or overall a value small enough for your use case.